# Show a discount field in the Product display page

Tags: commerce

I want to apply some discounts on products.
I know the Commerce discount module and its UI.
However,it would be much simpler for the site admin to have a second field on the product display for the discount-new lower price.
Is this possible to do?If so how?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer,with the use of this module https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_saleprice